# Why does ZwUnmapViewOfSection() unmap the memory of the whole process, when given the PE base address as argument?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

In code that creates a process in a suspended state and unmaps the program's memory, I often see the following code:

```
ZwUnmapViewOfSection(remoteProcessInfo->hProcess, static_cast<PVOID>(remoteImageBaseAddress))
```

According to the MSDN documentation, `ZwUnmapViewOfSection` unmaps a single section that contains the `remoteImageBaseAddress`.

However, PE binaries have multiple sections (`.text`, `.data` etc.), so doesn't this call only unmaps a single section of these?

What do I miss? I also don't understand why `remoteImageBaseAddress` (base address) is given as argument, as this address doesn't belong to the `.text` section (executable code).

Comment: *However, PE binaries have multiple sections* - you confuse [*Section* Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Memory/file-mapping) (on win32 language known as *FileMapping*) and PE sections - this is absolute different things.

Comment: and `ZwUnmapViewOfSection` unmap memory of concrete section (file mapping if want) but of course not whole process

Comment: Only one Section object is created when a file is mapped as `SEC_IMAGE`. PE sections correspond to this object's subsections. A Section object references a Segment Control Area, which has a singly linked list of subsections (for an image map, it's one for the header and one for each PE section). A subsection includes the number of prototype page table entries (PTEs), base PTE address, starting logical sector number (LSN) in the file, and number of sectors.

Comment: Section names like .text, .data etc are a linker implementation detail and specific to programs generated in a language like C.  That ends when the PE file is generated, the OS loader maps the whole shebang into memory.  Sections in the PE file that the OS loader knows about are identified by the [data directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winnt/ns-winnt-_image_data_directory).

Comment: @eryksun - `ZwCreateSection` or it shell `CreateFileMapping` always create (or open) only one Section (file mapping ) object. `SEC_IMAGE` here unrelated. section can be created and not from pe file or without file at all. the OP confuse Section (file mapping ) object with PE sections. this is different things

Comment: @RbMm, I did not mean to say that it's only a single Section object just for `SEC_IMAGE`, but rather to emphasize that it's still just one Section *even for* a file mapped as `SEC_IMAGE`. Then I clarified that PE sections are actually mapped as *subsections* in the Section's Segment Control Area and defined what a subsection is. Please explore this in a kernel debugger, and correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: but how internally this is implemented this is already not important here. all what i try say - file mapping and pe sections this is different things. `ZwUnmapViewOfSection` unmaps a whole view of a file mapping

Answer (score 2):

I think you are getting confused between PE file sections, and Windows's memory managment `Section` type object.

A section in a PE file is just a piece of raw data, usually categorized by their attributes.

In Windows, a `section` object is an internal memory management object that is used to map physical files on the disk to a process's virtual address space. So when `ZwUnmapViewOfSection` is passed the address of the mapped file (the section), it removes the section object - aka the mapped file, from kernel space and the process's address space. It does not alter the actual PE file's sections.

I hope you understand this now.